# Kofia hat not awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I made a post in after December 26 and I did not get the Kofia hat. Is this a bug? Does this mean that you make the first post on the site between 12/26 and 1/1 or does this get awarded when you make your first post in that date range? If the latter, there is a bug.

Comment: Looking at [this similar Meta.se question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246210/226928), it sounds like the post must have positive score to get the hat. Could that be it?

Comment: I wish I could give all of my hats to you so that you couldn't whine anymore in the 2014 winter bash.

Comment: @Venus  
Well, if you read my post, you would realize that I read that description. I was just confused about the "first post" part because it could mean many things. For example, look at other hat descriptions with the word "first" in them − the mean something else. So I wasn't whining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Description of Kofia hat says

> **first post** between $12/26$ and $1/1$

As mentioned in [this MetaSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246210/226928)

> It has to be the first post you did on a site. So if you've already left a question or answer on a site, you can't earn that hat for that site

If you still want to earn your hat you're welcome to make your *first post* on other SE sites.

Comment: Well, if you read my post, you would realize that I read that description. I was just confused about the "first post" part because it could mean many things. For example, look at other hat descriptions with the word "first" in them $-$ the mean something else.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta I hope it's clear now!

Comment: Thanks to [@alexwlchan](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18952/kofia-hat-not-awarded/18954?noredirect=1#comment68890_18954) for pointing out the MetaSE post.